# Finding bases for subspaces of Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve the following problem (for self-study).

> Let $V$ be a vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $4$. Find bases for the following subspaces of $V$:
> (a) $U_1 = \{p \in V \colon p(1) = p(2) = 0\}$
>
> (b) $U_2 = \{p \in V \colon p(1) = p(2)\}$

I'm having trouble getting started. For part (a), I considered some sort of "indicator functions" for $1$ and $2$. It seems to me that the space in (b) is infinite-dimensional because it's uniquely determined by the common value of $p(1) = p(2)$, of which there are infinitely possibilities, though that wouldn't make sense since $U_2$ is a subspace of a finite-dimensional space.

I'd appreciate some help on how to get started with these.

Comment: Since you are telling us your problem is only with (b), can you please edit your post to include what you did for (a)? (Better in your post than in comment)

Comment: If $p\in U_2$, what could you say about $p-p(1)$? And if $p\in U_1$, what could you say about $p+k$ for any constant $k$?

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry, I should have been clearer. I'm stuck on both parts, but I had an idea for (a) to use indicator functions. I don't know if it will work, though.

Comment: I do not see how you intend to use indicator functions. I think you should first concentrate this post on (a).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Ok, so if $p \in U_2$, then $p(1) = p(2) = 0$. I'm not sure how to. interpret $p - p(1)$, though the goal seems to be to find a corresponding element of $U_1$, if I'm not mistaken. If $p \in U_1$, then $p(1) = p(2) = 0$, so I think adding a constant to $p$ will lead to $(p+k)(1) = (p+k)(2) = k \neq 0$.

Comment: No, if $p\in U_2$, you don't have necessarily $p(1)=p(2)=0$. However, if $q=p-p(1)$, what's the value of $q(1)$ and $q(2)$? And, indeed, if $p\in U_1$, then with $q=p+k$, $q(1)=q(2)=k$. So $q\in U_2$, right? If you have a base of $U_1$, is there an obvious candidate for a base of $U_2$? Well, to begin with, can you show a base of $U_1$?

Comment: This answers your question (a) [Finding the basis of a subset of polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337160/finding-the-basis-of-a-subset-of-polynomials) (mutatis mutandis) Please focus on one question per post.